# Adding resolvers for Spark packages

Tags: maven, apache-spark

We can automatically fetch jars by:

- package coordinates to `spark.jars.packages`
- passing package coordinates with `--packages` option of `spark-submit`.

but how can we configure additional resolvers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Additional repositories can be provided using `--repositories` option:

```
bin/spark-shell --repositories https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases
```

or `spark.jars.repositories` in `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.jars.repositories    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases
```